# array_push into a multi-dimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a array with a key value you on it like:

```
$some_array['array_key'] = "some string";
```

Is it possible to use array_push to add more elements to the array?

Ive tried this:

```
array_push($some_array['array_key'],"another string");
```

and I have tried other obvious way, but nothing seems to work. Is it possible to add array_push into a array with key value?

Thanks for any help you can offer,

--Bryan

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want `$some_array['array_key']` to be an array of values, you have to initialize it as an array, like this:

```
$some_array['array_key'] = array('some string');
```

Only then can you use `array_push()` or the `[] =` notation:

```
$some_array['array_key'][] = 'another string';
```