# loop, push data into array

Tags: php, wordpress

I try to push each data from the Wordpress loop into array:

```
<?php 
$array = array(); 
        $args = -1;
        $posts = get_posts($args);      
        foreach ($posts as $post){
            array_push( $array, array(
                "title" => get_the_title(),
                //capire perchè non stampa il contenuto
                "cont" => get_the_content()
            )); 
        }
        print_r($array);
?>
```

The problem was that I want to have final data into the multidimensional array but I have only the title value but NOT the content.

Comment: possible duplicate of [array\_push into a multi-dimensional array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870847/array-push-into-a-multi-dimensional-array)

Comment: if i replace get_the_content()to the_content() the result is also empty

Comment: can you post an example please?

Comment: ok i replace the foreach with the standard Wordpress loop and it work

Comment: <?php 
$array = array(); 
        $args = -1;
        $posts = get_posts($args);      
        if ( have_posts() ) {
   while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post(); 
    array_push( $array, array(
      "title" => get_the_title(),
      //capire perchè non stampa il contenuto
      "cont" => get_the_content()
    ));
   } // end while
  } // end if
  print_r($array);
?>

Comment: Good idea, answer your own question though for other users who may be having this problem

Comment: @seanyt123 This will work and it is working. OP only issue is that the content is not being retrieved. See my answer why it didn't

Answer (score 1):

Your loop is fine. To access the content `get_the_content()` you need to use [`setup_postdata`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/setup_postdata). It sets up the global post data for template tags.

```
foreach ($posts as $post){
   setup_postdata($post);
   ...
}
```